# onKeyDown event handling not getting propagated in android

Tags: android, events

I have two Activities say A and B. The Activity A has event handling implementation for keys like CHANNEL_UP and CHANNEL_DOWN. Now, when Activity B is visible and any keys is pressed then finish is called on B. In such cases, the key handling should be propagated to Activity A. But Activity A's onKeyDown method is not even been called. The code for Activity B onkeyDown is mentioned below.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

    switch(keyCode) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_CHANNEL_UP:
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_CHANNEL_DOWN:
            finish();
            break;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't expect key events to be propagated like that.

Sounds like you may want to start B with `startActivityForResult` and then have it set the reason for finishing, which A can then handle.

Comment: That would be an option but as per documentation over http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.Callback.html#onKeyDown(int,android.view.KeyEvent) false should be returned in order to allow next receiver to handle it.

Comment: That's true, but you'll notice that it's within the "android.view" package.  It'll let other views handle the event, but they don't cross activity boundaries afaik.

Comment: I am not sure if that's the case. It seems that dispatchKeyEvent of Activity A is getting called but with action ACTION_UP may be because onkeydown is already handled in Activity B. Anyways, in my case the answer suggested by you may turn out better.

Comment: That's because the key is physically pressed (down) while B is active. It then finishes and the button is physically released when A is active. Not that the input event is sent to both activities.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried similar implementation(I use KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK), and it does not work either.

I guess that the keyevent ONLY propagates inside the activity, from child views to parent views and to Activity.

If the Activity is destroyed, the event is gone.